# Access GH ACTIONS_STEP_DEBUG from an SSH command / environment variable

Tags: github-actions

As far as I understood, the "secret" ACTIONS_STEP_DEBUG is set to true when you relaunch a workflow in "debug mode" on Github Actions for a repository.

Now I'd like to hook onto this like a switch to print additional information from python commands that are executed in my actions/steps.

Is it possible to turn ACTIONS_STEP_DEBUG into an environment variable or how could I access it from within a step (like bash or even in python)?

Comment: Why not just [log on level debug](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-a-debug-message)?

Comment: @rethab Because unfortunately the information I want to print is only available inside python scripts that are called during a step.

Comment: Are you aware that you can use write these debug messages from within a python program?

Answer (score 1):

So found I can use the secrets, to set an env, however only for workflows, not for the action, for some reason.

```
env:
  IS_STEP_DEBUG: ${{ secrets.ACTIONS_STEP_DEBUG }}
```